# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'indexOf': object is null or undefined in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Hi I got this error in IE. It works in all other browsers.

This is the line where error shows:

```
if (parseFloat(totalnumm.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g,'')) > compare_value_neww    &&  values[x].indexOf("Custom") > -1 ).
```

I googled and found one solution:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;FF=3;OtherUA=4" />
```

But it did not work for me.

Comment: That isn't enough code - `values` is the problematic item and we don't know what `values` is or how it's built.

Comment: Ya, is values[x] returning a string or array or what?

Comment: Hi wings everything is works fine still i  have'nt add values[x].so problem comes due to values[x]???

Comment: @WingsOfFire indexOf works on string in IE. It's just in older version of IE, array prototype doesn't implement method indexOf.

Comment: That `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag is really awful. The `IE=8` bit is bad, but occasionally possible to justify it. I'd suggest not using it though. The `FF=3` and `OtherUA=4` bits are just pointless, if not outright harmful. Those should definitely be thrown away.

Comment: hi Spudley please tell me the solution to resolve it...Thanks

Comment: Replaced the tags, since they were all irrelevant to the actual question. (retained the jQuery tag though, since the OP seems to be leaning toward the jQuery solution)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was going to ask what version of IE you're testing this in, but since you've specified `content="IE=8` in your meta tags, that's fairly irrelevant.

The short answer is that `.indexOf` for arrays is not supported in IE8 or earlier. (That includes later IE versions in compatibility mode, so your meta tag will mean that it won't work in any IE version)

Solutions:

1. **Use a library like jQuery (or similar) which supplies an `.inArray()` method that you can use instead.**

   You'll then need to change your code from using `var.indexOf(x)` to `$.inArray(var,x)`

   Pick this solution if you're already using jQuery (or another library that has this feature).
2. **Use a polyfill library like [this one](https://github.com/petermichaux/polyfill) that adds the standard `.indexOf` method to the Array prototype.**

   This should allow you to keep your existing code unchanged; just include the library.

   Use this solution if you are happy to use a library but you haven't got one already installed that would help.
3. **Write your own function that does the same job using a `for()` loop.**

   This is a complete change in how you find things in your arrays, but does mean you don't need to use any extra libraries.

   Use this solution if you don't want to (or can't, for whatever reason) use a third-party library.
4. **Remove your IE8 meta tag (it's pretty bad anyway, so that's a good idea) and only support your site for users with IE9 or better.**

   Use this solution if you're happy to stop supporting older IE versions.

   In fact, it would be a good idea to do this anyway; there's no good reason to be using the meta tag to force IE into compatibility mode. Better to set it to `content="IE=edge"`. That will remove the problem entirely for newer IE versions. If you do need to support IE8 or earlier, then this solution won't solve the problem and you'll need to also use one of the other solutions above, but I'd still recommend doing it anyway, because as things stand you are deliberately removing features from newer IE versions for no good reason.

Comment: what should i do please  help...any 1 valid solution??

Comment: @honey - edited the answer to include tips on which one to use.

Comment: Hi Spudely It looks this can solve the problem.what please tell me where i have to add it..                  jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )

Comment: @honey - see the example code in my solution 1; it's a direct replacement for `var.indexOf(x)`

Comment: hi Spudley there is no var.indexof() in my code please help ..your suggestion will definitely work.

Comment: @honey .... where "var" is a generic example name for any variable. In the code you quoted, it would be `values[x]`, so the code would be `$.inArray(values[x], "Custom")`. If you have other occurrences of `indexOf` in your code you may need to replace them as well; obviously the code in those cases would be different so I can't give exact help. But if you understand what the code is doing, it should be perfectly simple to do.

Comment: @honey - if it solves the problem, please click the tick icon next to the answer to mark it as "accepted".  :)