# IndexOf Internet Explorer to InArray, length fail

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, razor

I got the following error, Unable to get property 'slice'.
The problem occurs when I changed the code to make it compatible with IE.

```
            function change_hash(hash) {
                hash = hash.replace(/^.term/, 'category');
                window.location.href = '#' + hash;

                $('.pagination a').each(function () {

                    var item = $(this),
                        href = item.attr('href'),
                        //end_slice = href.indexOf('#') == -1 ? href.length : href.indexOf('#');
                        end_slice = $.inArray(href, '#') == -1 ? $('href').length : $.inArray(href, '#');

                    href = href.slice(0, end_slice); // PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
                    item.attr({ 'href': href + '#' + hash })
                })
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with C# at all.

Comment: @SpcCode Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: see the commented code? That does not work for Internet Explorer. I have to changed like suggested on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787799/script5007-unable-to-get-value-of-the-property-indexof-object-is-null-or-und. But now I got a new problem in the following line.

Answer (score 0):

@SpcCode: I guess issue is due to below line:
end_slice = $.inArray(href, '#') == -1 ? **$('href').length** : $.inArray(href, '#');

It should be: 
end_slice = $.inArray('#',href) == -1 ? href.length : $.inArray('#',href);

Comment: Change but now got this error:

Error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Problem here is href is an string not a array. so you need to do a small change in code as below:
var item = $(this),href=[];
href.push( item.attr('href'));
 var end_slice = $.inArray('#', href) == -1 ? href[0].length : $.inArray('#', href);